# faceted search using node-solr

Tags: node.js, solr

I am trying to confirm whether faceted search is available via node-solr or not.  Has anyone used the Solr functionality with nodejs and if so, can you kindly point to  an online resource/share sample code that displays the functionality.

Thanks

Comment: It appears it is - I will update the question with a working sample and additional info - hope it helps others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen solr-node-client:[solr-node-client][1]?

Comment: Thanks for commenting - I will do a comparison between the two when I get the chance over the next few weeks.

Comment: Any news about the comparison between the two? I am starting to use solr with node.js and am wordering which is the better one.

Answer (score 4):

Even though I couldn't find it in their official documentation- this is what got working for me.

```
var client = sails.solr;
var query = client.createQuery().q({
  'city_id': options.city_id,
  'content_auto': options.term,
})
.fl('sku')
.start(0)
.rows(2000)
.facet({'field':'brand'})
.facet({'field':'price'})
.facet({'field':'discount_percentage'})
.facet({'field':'pack_size'})
.facet({'field':'categories'})
var defer = sails.Q.defer();
client.search(query, function(err, obj){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error getting data from solr. Error: ' + err);
        return defer.reject(err);
    }
    return defer.resolve(obj);
});
return defer.promise;
```

Obviously- stumbled across it by good'ol trial and error!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, there is not very much documentation on this at all for node.  You can find bushels of examples and tutorials for solr with java, python, or php, but bloggers the people on the node/end-to-end js train seem pretty quiet.  I recommend [solr-client](https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client).  Follow the link on the README as well and the guy has about a dozen simple use examples.